# Get AsyncFunction constructor in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

So I'm trying to dynamically create AsyncFunctions in a Typescript Program. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncFunction) says that I can get the AsyncFunction constructor by

```
var AsyncFunction = Object.getPrototypeOf(async function () { }).constructor;
```

but typescript compiles this to

```
var AsyncFunction = Object.getPrototypeOf(function () {
    return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function* () { });
}).constructor;
```

The difference can be seen by simply attempting to use the constructor;

```
new AsyncFunction("return 1;")();
```

returns a Promise (what I need) when run in Firefox, but simply returns a `1`when run after being passed through typescript.

How can I stop Typescript from mangling my async functions?

Comment: When you use `tsc` to compile, are you targeting ES5?

Comment: I'm actually targeting es2015, but it still happens with es2017 and esnext.

Comment: @Giantblargg What version of tsc are you using? 
When targeting es2015 typescript will obviously continue to transpile your async function, it's not a part of the standard. But for me with tsc 2.2+  and targeting es2017 it doesn't transpile the async function.

Comment: Welp I'm an idiot, I wasn't saving my tsconfig.json file before recompiling. Seems to work correctly on es2017 and esnext despite what I said earlier.